# Get a PHP file to return text/plain to AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I'm working on a simple HTML form that either detects if a record exists (in an XML file) and populates all the fields OR detects that the form doesn't exist and on submit, creates the record (or modifies the current one if it's been modified)

I'm working on the part now that would add a non existing record and/or modify an existing one.

The AJAX calls a PHP file, and in the PHP file I'd like to check if the record exists or not and perform the appropriate operations accordingly. I would like the user of the form to be informed (no pun intended) of what operation was carried out (i.e. "Added the Record" or "Modified the Record").

To start with, all I have my PHP doing right now is returning the text `added`. I want to see if I can get "Added the Record" to properly display in original HTML file.

**EXPECTED:** When I click `Submit`, I expect the message "Added the Record" or "Modified the Record" to appear under the form, depending on the return from the PHP file.

**THE ERROR:** Now, when I click `Submit`, the form resets itself, adds all the parameters to the URL and I don't get any message from the AJAX request.

Here's my code:

HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javaScript">
            function checkID(val){
                if (val.value.length != 6) //Since student ID's are six digits
                    return;
                //inID = val.value;
                //if (inID.length < 6) return;

                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', 'processor.php?studentID=' + document.forms[0].elements[0].value);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    /**
                    if (xhr.readystate != 4 || xhr.status != 200){
                        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<p> Not Done Yet</p>";
                    }
                    **/
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
                        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "";
                        parse(xhr.responseXML); 
                    }
                }
                xhr.send();
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<p> Not Done Yet</p>";
            }
            function parse(xml){
                if (xml == null) alert("Null!");
                var student = xml.getElementsByTagName('student');
                    if (student.length == 0) alert("No Student's Found with that ID");
                var content = student.item('0');
                    var name = content.getElementsByTagName('fullname');
                    name = name.item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.forms[0].elements[1].value = name;

                    var phone = content.getElementsByTagName('phone');
                    phone = phone.item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.forms[0].elements[2].value = phone;

                    var email = content.getElementsByTagName('email');
                    email = email.item(0).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.forms[0].elements[3].value = email;

            }
            function addOrModify(curr){
                xhr2 = new XHRHttpRequest();
                xhr2.open('GET', 'addOrModify.php'); //?studentID=' + document.forms[0].elements[0].value);
                xhr2.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (xhr2.readyState === 4 && xhr2.status === 200){
                        if (xhr.responseText == "added") {document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<p>Added the Record</p>"};
                    }
                }
                xhr.send();
                return false;
            }

        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container {
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 30px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .centerp {
                font-size: 150%;
                text-align: center;
            }
            table {
                align: center;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Student Profile</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p class="centerp"> Student Profiles </p>
        <div id="container">
            <form>
                <table align="center">
                    <label>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Student ID</td> 
                            <td><input type="text" name="studentID" onblur="checkID(this)"> </input></label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td> 
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"> </input></label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Phone</td> 
                            <td><input type="text" name="phone"> </input></label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email</td> 
                            <td><input type="text" name="email"> </input></label></td>
                        </tr>
                    </label>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <input type="submit" onclick="return addOrModify()"> </input></td></tr> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <div id="status">
                                </div> </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Simple PHP page:

```
<?php


aOm();
function aOm(){
    header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    echo "added";
}

?>
```

Comment: Describe what is actually happening (errors, etc) and what you expect to happen, rather than "it's not working"

Comment: @PhillSparks Thanks for the constructive suggestion, I've added those portions in clearer form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minor typos in your code

```
function addOrModify(curr){
                xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest(); // xhr2 = new XHRHttpRequest();
                xhr2.open('GET', 'addOrModify.php'); //?studentID=' + document.forms[0].elements[0].value);
                xhr2.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (xhr2.readyState === 4 && xhr2.status === 200){
                        if (xhr2.responseText == "added") // if (xhr.responseText == "added")
                          {document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<p>Added the Record</p>"};
                        }

                }
                xhr2.send(); //xhr.send();
                return false;
            }
```

that should get it working. No mistakes in your php code though

Comment: It works! One thing is still bugging me; when I click submit, the browser adds all the [blank] info to the address line, even though I the `<form>` attributes are empty. Do you know why, and do you know how I can make that not happen? Thanks!

Comment: if you want to hide the params use POST instead of GET. Or if you wish to use GET you can validate form fields before initiating ajax call

Comment: I want to use get in the AJAX call but I don't want anything to appear in the address bar. Isn't there a way?